# Unknown behavior from cin

Tags: c++

First off I'd like to say I know that using getline is a better alternative, however, i am curious as to why this code doesn't work as intended: and I can't figure out why

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    while(1) {
        int input;
        cout << "---> ";
        cin >> input;
        if(cin.fail()) {
            char rd = cin.get();
            cout << "failure" << rd << "=" << cin.fail() << " " << endl;
        }
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Intended: if an integer is entered, continue otherwise cin fails, we pull one char from stdin and essentially output it.  Then we keep looping.

The way I see it, eventually cin.get() should clear up bad input; but it never does: it gets stuck in an infintie loop.  What?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cin.fail() detects whether the value entered fits the value defined in the variable.
But if cin.fail() is true, it means that

a) the entered value does not fit the variable

b) the varialbe will not be affected

c) the instream is still broken

d) the entered value is still in the buffer and will be used for the next "cin >> variable"statement.

Hence you have to do the following:

a) repair the instream via cin.clear();

b) clear the buffer with cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits::max(),'\n');

```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <string>
     using namespace std;

     int main() {

     while(1) {
     int input;
     cout << "---> ";
     cin >> input;
     if(cin.fail()) {
        char rd = cin.get();
        cout << "failure" << rd << "=" << cin.fail() << " " << endl;
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore();
        }
      }
    return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

After taking the input integer, it gets a newline as a character when you press enter. Same as for character input

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    while(1) {
        int input;
        cout << "---> ";
        cin >> input;
        getchar();
        if(cin.fail()) {
            char rd = cin.get();
            getchar();
            cout << "failure" << rd << "=" << cin.fail() << " " << endl;

        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```